# python unicode ... dictionary

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary

```
filename = "dict.json" 

def read_dict(filename):
    file = open( script_dir + filename )
    dict = json.load( file )
    file.close()
    return dict

 def test(dict):
   key = raw_input("enter key: ")
   for element in dict:
     while key in element:
       print element
       key = raw_input("key taken, try again: ")
   val = raw_input("enter val: ")
   new_element = {key:val}

   #lets get some clear output
   print new_element 
   print key
   dict.append(new_element)
        print dict
        #return dict


test(read_dict(filename))
```

Output:

```
^_^ python newnor.py
enter key: både
enter val: both
{'b\xc3\xa5de': 'both'}
både
[{u'foo': u'bar'}, {u'moo': u'mar'}, {'b\xc3\xa5de': 'both'}]
```

The foo bar and moo mar have all ready been set by me...  but what I am confused about is why when I print my key it is a normal string, but then when I create a dictionary ( new_element) it becomes the unicode funk...

I have tried playing with str() and unicode(), but no luck as of yet. Any ideas?

edit:

tried this:

```
import sys

def key():
    k = raw_input()
    k = k.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
    element = {k:"bar"}
    print element

key()
```

termianl:

```
^_^ python qtest.py 
både
{u'b\xe5de': 'bar'}
```

so at least there is a `u` infront of it...

Comment: You have one very strange prompt there.

Comment: i think it is going to be >_< rather soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input is encoded in the system encoding. You will need to decode it before using it.

```
s = s.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

Comment: error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` for `key = key.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())`

Comment: I'm still not getting any love. ill edit my question to show what I am doing.

Comment: but then how can I print the dictionary?

Comment: Your dictionary is printing fine. The representation of the string is being printed, which is correct.

Comment: so there is no way I could have a dictionary that looks like `{"både":"both"}` ?

Comment: @user969617: You can always print a custom representation of it, something like `print u'{%s}' % u', '.join(u'"%s":"%s"' % x for x in d.items())`. You can't override the default representation, though (at least not as far as I know, and I hope that's true).

Comment: @user969617: If it's possible for you, you could use Python 3, which will make all this simpler.

Comment: @ThomasK I had been... but thought I would play around with 2.7 as it has more libs. I know that 3 is unicode... but hey, I guess it will be fine :)